# doubts regrading Django PayPal app integration

Tags: django, paypal

I want to use "PayPal Pro" in my "Django" powered site. When i went through `pip install django-paypal documentation` i found that i have to use `db` for it as i have to mention it in `INSTALLED_APPS` and migrate it.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ..
    'paypal.standard',
    'paypal.pro',
]
```

But i am instructed not to use database at all. So how can i integrate PayPal in website without using db!Is there any detailed tutorial regarding this?

Comment: Django uses a database. You need to use a db.

Comment: @Hanny I am using existing but else db and using python requests.post/get method to get or post data.

Comment: I find this restriction very "weird" and a bad coding practice. Databases are optimized to store and retrieve data. The idea is that the data you store is not per se the one you retrieve in a next query (for example an aggregate), and furthermore database are optimized (with for example indices) to resolve queries as fast as possible. Not using a database will actually only make problems worse. What is true is that it requires some skill to write good queries, and design a good database, but this is with all technology: a certain skillset is required.